# Avoiding a For-loop when finding the solution to a set of polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

There are several examples and questions regarding `Map`, but I couldn't find what I need.

This is a minimal working example.

I have two functions

$\qquad f=x^4+y^4-1$,

and

$\qquad g=x^2-4$.

One way to find the solution set would be to find the values of $x$ from $g=0$ and then substitute those values into $f$. Then solve for $f=0$ to obtain the values of $y$. I need to club the corresponding values of $x$ and $y$ together to form the solution set.

I have correctly implemented a solution using a `For` loop. However, I was wondering if I could use a nested `Map` or something simpler. I come from a `C++` background and a `For` loop is the intuitive and normal solution for most work involving array manipulation. However, I think `For` loops hurt writing efficient code in `Mathematica` (I suppose).

Existing solution:

```
f = x^4 + y^4 - 1;
g = x^2 - 4;
solx = Solve[g == 0, x];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[solx], i++,
  solytemp = NSolve[(f /. solx[[i]]) == 0, y];
  temp = Flatten[{solx[[i]], #}] & /@ solytemp;
  If[i == 1, solxy = temp, AppendTo[solxy, #] & /@ temp;];
  ];
solxy
```

> ```
>  {{x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, 
>   {x -> -2, y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, 
>   {x -> 2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, 
>   {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}
> ```

Please note that this is an MWE and the actual polynomials may be of much higher order.

#### Update 1

The solutions are to be found in steps and then clubbed together, as the polynomials are big. I also use my own modules instead of `NSolve` depending on how the solution is to be obtained and the problem.

I am aware of using `Solve` for multiple polynomials, however I am refraining from using that as the system is huge.

```
Solve[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x, y}]
```

I was hoping if something like below could be used (the code below does not work)

```
{#1, #2} & /@ NSolve[(f /. #1) == 0, y] & /@ solx
```

#### Update 2

Using the answer given by @Jason, I could do the following to get the result:

```
f = x^4 + y^4 - 1
g = x^2 - 4
solx = Solve[g == 0, x];
solxy = Flatten[
  solf2[xtrial_] := 
   Union[#, xtrial] & /@ NSolve[(f /. xtrial) == 0, y]; (solf2[#] & /@
     solx), 1];
```

Is there a way to bypass assigning a function. I don't want to end up creating several functions. It is a good solution nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach to obtain same answer in steps is

```
Solve[g == 0, x];
N[Solve[f == 0 /. #]] & /@ %;
MapIndexed[Join[%%[[First[#2]]], #] &, %, {2}];
Flatten[%, 1]

(*  {{x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
     {x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}, 
    {{x -> 2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
     {x -> 2, y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}  *)
```

**Explanation**

In response to the request below by the OP, details follow.  The first two lines of code provide the `x` and `y` solutions.

```
(* {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}} *)
(* {{{y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
              {y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}, 
    {{y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
              {y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}} *)
```

The goal, now, is to associate the eight values for `y` with corresponding values of `x`.  To access each of the eight values individually, we must reach two levels down into the nested `List` above.  The third argument, `{2}`, of `MapIndexed` accomplishes this.  (If `{1}` or no third argument at all were used, `MaxIndexed` would process blocks of four `y` values at once, which is not what we desire.)  Next, note that, unlike `Map`, `MapIndexed` returns not only `y` values (represented by `#` or `#1`) but also their positions in the nested `List` (represented by `#2`).  So, for instance, `MapIndexed` returns not just  `{y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}` but also its index `{2, 3}`.  The `First[#2]` index, `2` in this case, is the index of the corresponding `x` value.  Finally, `Join` links them together, and `Flatten` eliminates an unneeded pair of `{}`.

Comment: Can you please explain the code a bit? Specially the `#2` and `{2}` at the end?

Comment: @Saurav  I have added an explanation to my answer.  Best wishes for the New Year.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, create a function that solves `f` for a given `x`

```
solf[xtrial_Rule] := 
 Prepend[#, xtrial] & /@ NSolve[(f /. xtrial) == 0, y]
```

which works like this

```
solf[x -> 2]
(* {{x -> 2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}} *)
```

and then `Apply` it to a list of replacement rules,

```
(solf @@@ solx)
(* {{{x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
   y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
   y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
   y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}, {{x -> 2, 
   y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
   y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
   y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}} *)
```

this has one extra dimension of list than your original solution, so you can `Flatten` once,

```
(solf @@@ solx)~Flatten~1
(* {{x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}} *)
```

**Edit**
If you don't want to have a defined function clogging up the main namespace, you can use a pure function like this,

```
Flatten[
 Function[xtrial, 
   Prepend[#, xtrial] & /@ NSolve[(f /. xtrial) == 0, y]] @@@ solx,
 1]
(* {{x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
  y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
  y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}} *)
```

Comment: Yeah, this works for the MWE provided. However, I have to find the solutions in steps, as the polynomials are big. We also use our own `Modules` instead of `NSolve` depending on how the solution is to be obtained and the problem.

Comment: I guess this works! I will wait for sometime to see if someone posts a better solution and then accept.

Answer (score 2):

`MapIndexed` generally makes a good replacement for `For` as it provides the indexed as it maps.

```
f = x^4 + y^4 - 1;
g = x^2 - 4;
solx = Solve[g == 0, x];

Flatten[
 MapIndexed[
  Function[{value, index},
   Flatten /@ Thread[{First@solx[[First@index]], #} &[value]]],
  Map[NSolve[# == 0, y] &, (f /. #) & /@ solx]],
 1]
```

> {{x -> -2, y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
>     y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
>     y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2, 
>     y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
>     y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
>     y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, 
>     y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2, y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You say: The solutions are to be found in steps and then clubbed together...  Here is my suggestion:

```
solx = Solve[x^2 - 4 == 0, x];
soly = NSolve[x^4 + y^4 - 1 == 0, y] /. solx;
solution = {solx[[#]], soly[[#]]} & /@ Range[1, Length@solx]

{{{x -> -2}, {{y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {y -> 
     1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {y -> 
     1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}},

 {{x -> 2}, {{y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {y -> 
     1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {y -> 
     1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) can handle multiple equations

```
f[x_, y_] = x^4 + y^4 - 1;

g[x_] = x^2 - 4;

eqns = {f[x, y], g[x]} == 0 // Thread;
```

Exact solutions

```
soln = Solve[eqns, {x, y}]

(*  {{x -> -2, y -> -(-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> -2, y -> (-I)*(-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> -2, y -> I*(-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> -2, y -> (-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> 2, y -> -(-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> 2, y -> (-I)*(-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> 2, y -> I*(-15)^(1/4)}, 
   {x -> 2, y -> (-15)^(1/4)}}  *)
```

Verification

```
eqns /. soln

(*  {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}}  *)
```

Or for more complex systems of equations you may need to use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) for approximate solutions

```
(soln2 = NSolve[eqns, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]) // N

(*  {{x -> -2., y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2., 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2., y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> -2.,
   y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2., y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2., 
  y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2., y -> 1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, {x -> 2., 
  y -> 1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}  *)
```

Verification

```
eqns /. soln2

(*  {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}}  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Howzabout

```
Remove[solveAndBacksubstitute];
solveAndBacksubstitute[{pair : {_, _}}, opts___] := 
  NSolve[pair[[1]] == 0, pair[[2]], opts]
solveAndBacksubstitute[pairs : {{_, _} ..}, opts___] := Module[{
    partlsoln, recurse },
  partlsoln = NSolve[#[[1]] == 0, #[[2]], opts] &[First[pairs]];
  recurse[varValue_] := Join[varValue, #] & /@ 
    solveAndBacksubstitute[Rest[pairs] /. varValue];
  Join @@ (recurse /@ partlsoln)
]
```

Then, usage:

```
f = x^4 + y^4 - 1;
g = x^2 - 4;
solveAndBacksubstitute[{{g, x}, {f, y}}]
(*  {{x -> -2., y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
     {x -> -2., y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, 
     {x -> -2., y ->  1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
     {x -> -2., y ->  1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, 
     {x ->  2., y -> -1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
     {x ->  2., y -> -1.39158 + 1.39158 I}, 
     {x ->  2., y ->  1.39158 - 1.39158 I}, 
     {x ->  2., y ->  1.39158 + 1.39158 I}}  *)
solveAndBacksubstitute[{{g, x}, {f, y}}, WorkingPrecision -> 8]
(*  {{x -> -2.0000000, y -> -1.3915788 - 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x -> -2.0000000, y -> -1.3915788 + 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x -> -2.0000000, y ->  1.3915788 - 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x -> -2.0000000, y ->  1.3915788 + 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x ->  2.0000000, y -> -1.3915788 - 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x ->  2.0000000, y -> -1.3915788 + 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x ->  2.0000000, y ->  1.3915788 - 1.3915788 I}, 
     {x ->  2.0000000, y ->  1.3915788 + 1.3915788 I}}  *)
```

Commentary:  There's no `For[]` loop.  Also, since you are using a complicated inner function (`NSolve[]`) for which there are many options that you will eventually find you need to tweak, options are received by `solveAndBacksubstitute[]` and passed straight to `NSolve[]`.  (We could be fancy and filter out only those options that `NSolve[]` understands, but I don't see much value for this kind of complexity here.)

I can see a few directions for more fussiness:

- We could use a `TimeConstrained[]` and `MemoryConstrained[]` `Solve[]` to try to get simple, exact answers and fall back to `NSolve[]` if the time or intermediate expression swell is too great.
- We could feed in a sequence of solve functions, for instance "`{Solve, NSolve, Solve, DSolve, Solve, NDSolve}`", to indicate which solve function to use for each of the steps of processing the list.
- We could write a helper function to go from "`{func1, func2, ...}, {var1, var2, ...}`" to "`{{func1, var1}, {func2, var2}, ...}`", but since this is just `Transpose[{{func1, func2, ...}, {var1, var2, ...}}]`, I didn't bother.